# TeXstudio tooltip/autocomplete dialog off screen

Tags: texstudio

While using TeXstudio, the tooltip/autocomplete menu sometimes goes off screen so that I can no longer see the suggestions. Here is a screen shot:

[image: Tooltip off screen]

How can I fix this issue?

I am using TeXstudio version 2.9.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 with the GNOME-shell D.E.

Comment: same here on 2.10.8 and I'm thinking it's a bug

Comment: related bug report: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1688/

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1688/ states this bug as fixed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report.